# Why are events positioned absolutely on SharePoint 2010 calendar views?

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm looking through the source of one of my SharePoint 2010 pages that has a calendar view and I'm trying to figure out why the elements are being positioned absolutely and occur after the table that makes up the actual calendar frame.

For example...

The calendar is created like this:

```
<tbody><tr>
        <th></th><th class="ms-acal-month-top"><nobr><span style="display: inline;">Sunday</span><span style="display: none;">S</span></nobr></th><th class="ms-acal-month-top"><nobr><span style="display: inline;">Monday</span><span style="display: none;">M</span></nobr></th><th class="ms-acal-month-top"><nobr><span style="display: inline;">Tuesday</span><span style="display: none;">T</span></nobr></th><th class="ms-acal-month-top"><nobr><span style="display: inline;">Wednesday</span><span style="display: none;">W</span></nobr></th><th class="ms-acal-month-top"><nobr><span style="display: inline;">Thursday</span><span style="display: none;">T</span></nobr></th><th class="ms-acal-month-top"><nobr><span style="display: inline;">Friday</span><span style="display: none;">F</span></nobr></th><th class="ms-acal-month-top"><nobr><span style="display: inline;">Saturday</span><span style="display: none;">S</span></nobr></th>
    </tr><tr class="ms-acal-summary-dayrow">
        <th title="May 26 - June 01" rowspan="2" evtid="week" date="5/26/2013"><div class="ms-acal-month-weeksel">

        </div></th><td class="" evtid="day" date="5/26/2013"><div>
            <nobr>26 </nobr>
        </div></td><td evtid="day" date="5/27/2013"><div>
            <nobr>27 </nobr>
        </div></td><td evtid="day" date="5/28/2013"><div>
            <nobr>28 </nobr>
        </div></td><td evtid="day" date="5/29/2013"><div>
            <nobr>29 </nobr>
        </div></td><td evtid="day" date="5/30/2013"><div>
            <nobr>30 </nobr>
        </div></td><td evtid="day" date="5/31/2013"><div>
            <nobr>31 </nobr>
        </div></td><td evtid="day" date="6/1/2013"><div>
            <nobr>1 </nobr>
        </div></td>
    </tr><tr class="ms-acal-summary-itemrow">
        <td><div class="ms-acal-outday">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-outday">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-outday">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-outday">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-outday">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-outday">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-day6">

        </div></td>
    </tr><tr class="ms-acal-summary-dayrow">
        <th title="June 02 - June 08" rowspan="2" evtid="week" date="6/2/2013"><div class="ms-acal-month-weeksel">

        </div></th><td class="" evtid="day" date="6/2/2013"><div>
            <nobr>2 </nobr>
        </div></td><td evtid="day" date="6/3/2013"><div>
            <nobr>3 </nobr>
        </div></td><td evtid="day" date="6/4/2013"><div>
            <nobr>4 </nobr>
        </div></td><td evtid="day" date="6/5/2013"><div>
            <nobr>5 </nobr>
        </div></td><td evtid="day" date="6/6/2013"><div>
            <nobr>6 </nobr>
        </div></td><td evtid="day" date="6/7/2013"><div>
            <nobr>7 </nobr>
        </div></td><td evtid="day" date="6/8/2013"><div>
            <nobr>8 </nobr>
        </div></td>
    </tr><tr class="ms-acal-summary-itemrow">
        <td><div class="ms-acal-day0">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-day1">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-day2">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-day3">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-day4">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-day5">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-day6">

        </div></td>
    </tr><tr class="ms-acal-summary-dayrow">
        <th title="June 09 - June 15" rowspan="2" evtid="week" date="6/9/2013"><div class="ms-acal-month-weeksel">

        </div></th><td class="" evtid="day" date="6/9/2013"><div>
            <nobr>9 </nobr>
        </div></td><td evtid="day" date="6/10/2013"><div>
            <nobr>10 </nobr>
        </div></td><td class="" evtid="day" date="6/11/2013"><div>
            <nobr>11 </nobr>
        </div></td><td class="" evtid="day" date="6/12/2013"><div>
            <nobr>12 </nobr>
        </div></td><td evtid="day" date="6/13/2013"><div>
            <nobr>13 </nobr>
        </div></td><td evtid="day" date="6/14/2013"><div>
            <nobr>14 </nobr>
        </div></td><td evtid="day" date="6/15/2013"><div>
            <nobr>15 </nobr>
        </div></td>
    </tr><tr class="ms-acal-summary-itemrow">
        <td><div class="ms-acal-day0">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-day1">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-day2">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-day3">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-day4">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-day5">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-day6">

        </div></td>
    </tr><tr class="ms-acal-summary-dayrow">
        <th title="June 16 - June 22" rowspan="2" evtid="week" date="6/16/2013"><div class="ms-acal-month-weeksel">

        </div></th><td class="" evtid="day" date="6/16/2013"><div>
            <nobr>16 </nobr>
        </div></td><td class="" evtid="day" date="6/17/2013"><div>
            <nobr>17 </nobr>
        </div></td><td class="" evtid="day" date="6/18/2013"><div>
            <nobr>18 </nobr>
        </div></td><td class="" evtid="day" date="6/19/2013"><div>
            <nobr>19 </nobr>
        </div></td><td class="" evtid="day" date="6/20/2013"><div>
            <nobr>20 </nobr>
        </div></td><td evtid="day" date="6/21/2013"><div>
            <nobr>21 </nobr>
        </div></td><td evtid="day" date="6/22/2013"><div>
            <nobr>22 </nobr>
        </div></td>
    </tr><tr class="ms-acal-summary-itemrow">
        <td><div class="ms-acal-day0">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-day1">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-day2">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-day3">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-day4">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-day5">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-day6">

        </div></td>
    </tr><tr class="ms-acal-summary-dayrow">
        <th title="June 23 - June 29" rowspan="2" evtid="week" date="6/23/2013"><div class="ms-acal-month-weeksel">

        </div></th><td evtid="day" date="6/23/2013"><div>
            <nobr>23 </nobr>
        </div></td><td class="" evtid="day" date="6/24/2013"><div>
            <nobr>24 </nobr>
        </div></td><td evtid="day" date="6/25/2013"><div>
            <nobr>25 </nobr>
        </div></td><td class="" evtid="day" date="6/26/2013"><div>
            <nobr>26 </nobr>
        </div></td><td evtid="day" date="6/27/2013"><div>
            <nobr>27 </nobr>
        </div></td><td evtid="day" date="6/28/2013"><div>
            <nobr>28 </nobr>
        </div></td><td evtid="day" date="6/29/2013"><div>
            <nobr>29 </nobr>
        </div></td>
    </tr><tr class="ms-acal-summary-itemrow">
        <td><div class="ms-acal-day0">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-day1">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-day2">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-day3">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-day4">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-day5">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-day6">

        </div></td>
    </tr><tr class="ms-acal-summary-dayrow">
        <th title="June 30 - July 06" rowspan="2" evtid="week" date="6/30/2013"><div class="ms-acal-month-weeksel">

        </div></th><td evtid="day" date="6/30/2013"><div>
            <nobr>30 </nobr>
        </div></td><td class="" evtid="day" date="7/1/2013"><div>
            <nobr>1 </nobr>
        </div></td><td class="" evtid="day" date="7/2/2013"><div>
            <nobr>2 </nobr>
        </div></td><td class="" evtid="day" date="7/3/2013"><div>
            <nobr>3 </nobr>
        </div></td><td evtid="day" date="7/4/2013"><div>
            <nobr>4 </nobr>
        </div></td><td evtid="day" date="7/5/2013"><div>
            <nobr>5 </nobr>
        </div></td><td evtid="day" date="7/6/2013"><div>
            <nobr>6 </nobr>
        </div></td>
    </tr><tr class="ms-acal-summary-itemrow">
        <td><div class="ms-acal-day0">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-outday">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-outday">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-outday">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-outday">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-outday">

        </div></td><td><div class="ms-acal-outday">

        </div></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And then events show up farther down in the DOM as:

```
    <div class="ms-acal-item ms-acal-color5" style="position:absolute;left:810px;top:153px;width:153px;height:37px;" title="ABC
3:00 pm - 4:00 pm ABCMeeting" _index="1,0"><div class="ms-acal-sdiv"><div class="ms-acal-time">3:00 pm - 4:00 pm</div><div class="ms-acal-title"><a target="_blank" href="/sites/asdf/calendars/Lists/abc/DispForm.aspx?ID=3">ABC Meeting</a></div></div></div>
```

This is causing me endless frustration in trying to get a calendar to print properly from a browser. My question is:

**What is the reasoning behind positioning items absolutely in divs later in the DOM versus just putting the events inside the table cell elements?**

Comment: I suppose the reason is that some items span days and there is no simple way of having the items that fit into a cell flow around those that span cells.  If every item fit in a single day this design would have probably been avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I don't the answer to this, but thought it worth mentioning that it doesn't work that way in SP2007. In the earlier version, the events ARE placed inside the  tags ...

(I'm in the middle of trying to figure out how SP2007 gets events to span two or more days in the calendar, if anyone cares to share any info on that.)

Comment: I appreciate your response; however, if you are not posting an answer, you should leave this in the comments on the original post.